# i have sql dataframe how to manupulate it into required json format

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe

```
  dd1
  c1      | c2 
  test1   | 200
  test2   | 300
  test3   | 150
```

i want this dataframe somthing like this in json format

```
     [{name:"total",children:[{name:"test1",value:100},{name:"test2",value:300},{name:"test3",value:150}]}]
```

Comment: Where does the name "total" and "children" come from?

Comment: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/sunburst-chart/  please refer this link because i want data in this format

Comment: Share your work before you can get input.